# VSCode, how do I hide specified typings and suggestions in typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autosuggest

Question 1;

Hello, I am using typescript and VSCode, and I installed the great of packages 「@material-ui/core」 and 「@emotion」, both of they is export "styled" like this.

```
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core'
import styled from '@emotion/styled/types/base'
```

Image: export style from @material-ui/core
[image]

Image:  export styled from @emotion
[image]

I want to hide the suggestion of "styled" of 「@material-ui/core」, keep 「@emotion」.

How do I achieve that?

Question 2;

The amazing 「@material-ui/core」support log of 「aria-*」 props, but in my case, I definitely don't need those props, how can I make it un-suggestion?

Image: props of aria-*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
One of your imports have to use import alias, otherwise you'll have variable's name conflict.

```
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core'
import styled as emotionStyled from '@emotion/styled/types/base'
```

Or:

```
import { styled as materialStyled } from '@material-ui/core'
import styled from '@emotion/styled/types/base'
```

Q2:
In theory you are able to edit this package's `d.ts` file, which holds typings, that vscode use for autocomplete. However I would not suggest to do it, editing some third-party package code is definitely not recommended.

Comment: thank you for your reply, about Q1, I want to un-suggestion the "Auto Import" for @material-ui/core, therefore I don't need to review which one is my preference to import. It's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "auto import" ?

Comment: When I trigger the command of "trigger suggest", as you can see in this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aTf0.png

Comment: ok, I found a way that is declared a module "XXX" {} in d.ts